# Find condition under which variables fall away

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, algebraic-manipulation

I have a somewhat lengthy expression, looking like

```
expr = 1 + x + b + Pi + 2*a
```

Is there some way of generating a relationship between `a` and `b` that makes the parameters fall away? In the example above, that condition could look like `a -> -b/2` or `2*a == -b`, because inserting that yields the new expression

```
expr2 = 1 + Pi
```

which is independent of both `a` and `b`. Note that the relationship contains only the two variables; it leaves the terms not involving them intact (namely `x`), in other words: `a` can depend only on `b` in the desired solution (if there is one of course).

I tried my best using the usual suspects (`Reduce`, `Solve`, `SolveAlways`, ...), but couldn't come up with a solution.

*Background:* My expression is a physical quantity that has certain mathematical parameters left in it. Being physical, it may not depend on the choice of the leftover parameters, ergo these parameters are not independent of each other. I would like to get rid of these placeholders, and doing so will tell me something about the physics in the ansatz that lead to the whole calculation.

Comment: In the actual problem, do you have only two parameters or more?

Comment: I currently have only two parameters. (A solution with more than that would be nice, but I don't strictly need it.)

Comment: Is *any* condition that gets rid of $a$ and $b$ acceptable?  You could use `a -> -b/2 + 1` too.  It seems like in general you're looking for a relationship between $a$ and $b$, which, if satisfied, makes `expr` a constant (not depend on $a,b$).  But it seems that `Solve[expr == const, {a,b}]` will do this for you no matter how you choose `const`.  It can be `1+Pi`, it can be `0` or anything else.

Comment: @Szabolcs Edited the question, should be clearer now

Answer (score 1):

Something like :

```
vars = {a, b};

Reduce[expr == (expr /. Thread[Rule[vars, 0]]), vars]
```

A bit more generally :

```
Simplify[expr == Total[Cases[expr, _?(Function[{x}, And @@ (FreeQ[x, #] & /@ vars)][#] &)]]]
```

Comment: Is there a way I can generalize this so that `a` can only depend on `b` and nothing else present in `expr`? (I edited my question to make this a bit clearer)

Comment: My intention was to define all parameters you want to get rid of in `vars`. If you provide an example where my suggestion fails I'll try again.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that

```
Solve[expr == const, {a,b}]
```

will give you such a condition for any choice of `const`.  You can write `1+Pi` in place of `const` to get the example condition you gave, but you can also write `0` which gives another relationship that, when substituted back, gets rid of `a` and `b`.

It seems it is just a plain `Solve` you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, this doesn't ensure `a` depends only on `b` and not on any other variables in `expr`, a thing I didn't write clearly enough in my question. (I edited it a little now)

Comment: @David I see the edit.  I think that's not possible *in general*, e.g. `expr = 1 + a x + b`. But most of the time when it is possible, I think `Solve[0 == expr /. x -> const, {a,b}]` should give a correct solution.  It's possible to check by backsubstituting to `expr`.  If `a,b` don't go away after backsubstitution and simplification, it's probably not possible.